# Is there any implementation of type-safe, compile-time checked printf?

Tags: c++

I saw many implementation of type-safe printf, but most of them are using exception to raise type errors.

As exercise, I implemented prototype of printf-like formatting using string literals, and it seems to solve all the problems with old, good printf family (except using format read from external source which is always not safe).

**Example:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "const char*: %s, std::string: %s\n"_format("ONE", std::string{"TWO"});
    std::cout << "user defined: %*\n"_format(std::complex<int>{1, 2});
    std::cout << "hex: 0x%x, int: %d\n"_format(16, 123);
    std::cout << "double.2: %.2f, double: %f\n"_format(13.123123, 12.1);

    std::string s = "p(%d, %d)\n"_format(123, 234);
    std::cout << s;

//    not yet working
//    int x, y;
//    std::cin >> "p(%d, %d)"_format(x, y);
//    "p(%d, %d)"_format(x, y) = "p(999, 888)";
}
```

Full, dirty and not complete nor optimized code is  [here](https://gist.github.com/pawelrejkowicz/509a3a4cbd04e37003e52ee30ac26fea)

Generated `.s` shows that no text processing is done in runtime, even if variables are not `const`, but taken for example from `argv`. Passing wrong variable type, or using argument count cause ugly compilation error, which could be improved with static asserts or concepts.

This is only exercise, and the question is: Is it any library, which supports such constructions, and why such approach is not part of c++ standard?

Comment: It *is* part of the C++ standard. It's called `std::cout` which makes it so you cannot have a type error when doing `std::cout << something;`. Additionally compilers like gcc are able to check the format string at compile time, so your solution doesn't actually have an advantage over that. There are also plenty of implementations to be found for example [here](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=printf&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: You can use regular `print`-like functions with corresponding format checking annotations such as `_Printf_format_string_` or `__attribute__((format))`

Comment: You cannot, in general, check calls to `printf` at compile time as the format string may be generated at runtime.

Comment: @BaummitAugen True, but this alternative doesn't support runtime generated format strings either.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, it is not a complete alternative to `printf`, as it lacks that feature.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It is not a feature, it is more like a `printf` flaw.

Comment: All `printf` implementation using `const char*`, so type checking can't be done during compilation time. `std::cout` is type-safe, but ugly and hard to use, when you want to print something more complicated. Relying on implementation dependent checking or static analyzers is not nice. `printf` in addition does not support user defined types.

Comment: As I said, runtime gernerated format is not supported, but it is like `eval` in python...

Comment: I don't know of a library the implements it, but there is this [paper by Andrei Alexandrescu](https://erdani.com/publications/cuj-2005-08.pdf).

Comment: @StoryTeller I saw this paper, but now, we have all tools to do it without changes in c++ core.

Comment: @ziomq1991 - Yes, I'm aware of that. But plugging in modern C++ features into the approach presented by Alexandrescu is not too difficult an exercise. I recall a lecture he gave about the topic, after C++11 came out. Even implemented it in his slides. I'm having trouble finding *that* at the moment. But there you go.

Comment: @StoryTeller It's probably somewhere on CppCon's Youtube channel or on Channel 9, if anyone wants to look for it. May have been a talk at Going Native 2012 or 13 actually.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - Going native 2012 it is! Thanks. Here's the link to anybody who's interested https://youtu.be/_zgq6_zFNGY?t=22m57s

Comment: I saw this video, it uses throw to raise an type error, so it is useless.

Comment: @ziomq1991 - Ah, so you are in the anti-exception crowd. Okay.

Comment: @StoryTeller I like exceptions, but if something can be checked during compile-time, it should be do then

Comment: There are [attempts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptba_AqFYCM) to include a new formatting library into the standard. But doing compile time format string analyzing is not a goal in general. String formatting is usually not a bottleneck. But using your idea, there's a code bloat (compared to printf). In my opinion, if someone wants to create a formatting library, one should focus on: printf style, minimal code size while being fast.

Comment: @geza This video shows another runtime checking, which is unaccepted, especially when you want to run the code on embedded system, which is not always cheap. String formatting maybe isn't bottleneck in performance, but bugs caused by it can stop project for some time (e. g. problem with `printf(str);`, which is not detected by any tool). Probably literal format library would look awfull, but machine code generated by it is even smaller than printf generates.

Comment: @ziomq1991: I think that the presented library doesn't need runtime checking at all. As parameters can be referenced by `{}`, and the value gets formatted automatically. How can your solution be smaller? Each call of `_format` will generate a lot of code, doesn't it? While `printf` generates just `push`es, and a call. Cannot be smaller.

Comment: @geza you're right, literals would generete more code, but it would generate less if there is only few `printfs` in code, and there is no `printf` in `.so` (no real life usecase :). Literals can still call `printf` under the hood, with no overhead, checked types and with support for user-defined types, if good implemented.

Comment: @ziomq1991, don't forget to select an answer if your question has been answered.

Comment: @geza -- I just spent 4 days tracking down a corruption due to a bad argument to printf.... Having a compile time check would have saved thousands of dollars for my client in this one instance alone.

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin: well, 6 years later, I don't really remember what I had in mind. I think my comment was about, that instead of having compile-time checks, design a formatting library, which doesn't need a compile-time check, because the API doesn't need one. For example, if you consider fmtlib, and if you only use "{}" (no precision, modifiers.), then the only mistake one can make is that the number of parameters are not OK. But other than that, formatting just works. And if you want to extend the library to have precision modifiers, it can be done differently.

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin: for example, in my codebase, I format like this: `print("average: {}", ffloat(avg, 5, 2));`. In other words, instead of putting the precision to the string, I put it into little formatter objects. This way there is no need to have compile-time string validation. I've been using this technique for more than 20 years without any problems.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) and C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) have compile-time format string checks. For example (https://godbolt.org/z/vr57bqzb3):

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  std::string s = fmt::format("{:d}", "I am not a number");
}
```

gives a compile-time error because `d` is an invalid format specifier for a string. This uses Python-like format string syntax, not printf syntax though.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any such libray?  Sort of:  GCC (and other compilers) understand the syntax of `printf` format strings, and can be persuaded to issue a compile time error if the types don't match.

Why is such an approach not part of C++?  Because Bjarne originally came up with iostream which also does typesafe IO, and nobody has felt strongly enough about this to come up with an alternative proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Using *variadic templates*, you can simply have a custom typesafe version of printf:

```
void printf_d(const char* msg) {
    while (*msg) {
        if (*msg == '%') {
            throw std::runtime_error("The parameters are not given properly.");
        }
        std::cout << *msg++;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
void printf_d(const char* msg, T arg, Rest... args) {
    while (*msg) {
        if (*msg == '%') {
            std::cout << arg;
            msg++;
            printf_d(msg, args...);
            return;
        }
        std::cout << *msg++;
    }

};
```

Check it:

```
const char* msg = "% my name is % % and I am % years old, I live in % - The % used to specify the arguments.";
printf_d(msg, "Hello", "NAME", "SURNAME", 100, "Hamburg", '%');
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is NAME SURNAME and I am 100 years old, I live in Hamburg - The % used to specify the arguments.
```

Comment: And how exactly is this type-safe? You are not checking, for example, that the type of `arg` matches the format specified (e.g., if `%d` is found, are you checking to make sure that the `arg` corresponding to this format specification is in fact an integral? In general, this is by far not a trivial problem. The `fmt` library addition in C++20 is meant to solve this. Even the existing `std::printf`, `std::snprintf`, and so on, are not type safe.